# Check Panasonic battery production date

Tags: battery

I bought a Panasonic battery. A code is shown on the battery.
I am afraid the production date maybe 2014.

**How can I determine of production date of this battery ?**

[image: Pansonic Battery LC-P1228P]

I've checked with the supplier and they said batteries are made with 2016.

Comment: Just checking, but are there any other stamps on the battery?  Like, on different edges than can be seen in this pic?

Comment: Where did you buy the battery from?  Apparently, Panasonic batteries that are installed at the Toyota factory don't have the standard marking on them.  Do you not trust whoever sold it to you?  Why?  On the good side, apparently, this model of battery is *very* good and will last for many years longer than a cheap battery.

Comment: @ZachMierzejewski [1] , No just that one label and its just on top side .

Comment: @ZachMierzejewski . I've rechecked with their sales manager and send this photo , they said this batteries produced at start month of 2015 . I bought this battery for 47$ and they have "First Power(Chinese brand)" with middle 2016 production date for 57$ .    I want use this batteries for Solar PV . send back this panasonic and buy first power or use this batteries ?

Comment: I would 1000% go with the Panasonic battery over the Chinese battery.  If the sales manager is changing their story, I would bet that the code actually means it was manufactured 2014-12-03 (December 3rd, 2014).  (It is a bit unusual though for a battery to specify it's year with *two* numbers.)

Comment: @ZachMierzejewski, maybe not for this battery, it is rated for a 10 year life in standby applications. $47 is a **very** good price on this battery, Mouser lists them at $91.94 each for 30 units. That makes me think that they may be out of date, so you may well be right about the marking being the date code. I'd suggest calling an authorized distributor (in the US, Mouser or Digikey would be candidates).

Comment: For what it is worth, these don't appear to be automotive batteries. The listings that I've found for them say they are for standby applications (alarms, UPS, etc.).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about batteries for solar power applications. Also, we're mostly speculating about what the marks on the battery mean…

Comment: The application may be non automotive however a battery is a battery and the question was in reference to date of manufacture and could be valid in the case of a automotive battery as well. I would vote to keep it open.

Comment: Assuming that the seller is not lying about the date code it could be that Panasonic is using their fiscal year in their date codes.

Comment: @resident_heretic, if the question was about the process of finding and decoding date codes or the concerns related to batteries as they age, I would tend to agree, but as it stands that's not what seems to be being asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume it follows the usual production coding sequences.

14 =2014

12 =12th week

03 =3rd day of the week

A= the production shift

Tuesday March 18th 2014 on the day shift.

Comment: Is that coding a standard of some sort? If it is it would be cool to have a reference to it.

Comment: Yes, one of many variants

Answer (score 1):

For the record, the Panasonic Datecode format is YYMMDD + shift indication letter.

This is explained into the Panasonic VRLA Technical Handbook INDUSTRIAL BATTERIES FOR PROFESSIONALS available at https://eu.industrial.panasonic.com/sites/default/pidseu/files/downloads/files/panasonic-batteries-vrla-for-professionals_interactive.pdf

Comment: There you go..thanks for the confirmation . These kind of codes are used in a variety of manufacturing environments. .with a few variants such Julian date code, YMD code, some use year,week, day, shift. Sometimes date codes encoded in lot numbers, etc